# What does this error [NSUnknownKeyException] mean in xcode (objective c)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am running my app and when I click a navigation button which is supposed to take me to a TableViewController, it crashes, giving me this error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key index.'

It is also highlighting where the error occurred, pointing to this line in my DataTableViewController class:

```
CoordinatesCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CoordinatesCustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

I really have no idea what this means and could use some help

github for code: https://github.com/nneeranjun/Maps.git

Comment: In your github code some of files are missing

Comment: Ok, I was able to fix the error. Now it is not crashing, but when I try to set values for the labels, they are not showing up. Also, what files are missing. I uploaded everything via xcode?

Comment: CoordinatesCustomCell.m reference is there in xcode but not physically file exist

Comment: What had happened before was I had set CoordinatesCustomCell.h to extend UITableViewController instead of UITableViewCell. However, when I changed it, I guess the .m file got messed up so i deleted them and added new ones and it started working

Answer (score 0):

this problem maybe caused in xib or stroryboard. Check the class or any other attributes in it of your cell.

Comment: all of the classes and  reuse identifiers match

Comment: @nilayneeranjun As well as the subviews?

Comment: Subviews in the cell, check answers in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reasonthis-class-is-not-key-valu?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Check your cell and subviews custom class and connections with owner.[image]